# Diminishing returns based on distance within a square

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, terrain

In short I'm smoothing a terrain (2d heightmap) from a generated value back to its original value over distance.

There is a 6 unit flat zone that just uses the generated value, followed by a 3 unit smoothing zone that moves from generated back to original (making 9 total)

in the flat zone all x,z values are assigned a y value of say 4 for example then the 3 smooth units should move back to zero, meaning 3, then 2, then 1, which would make the next step (outside of the equation) back at 0 if zero is our original number.

From trial and error it seems I need to calculate the corners and the edges separately because the max distance of a corner is diagonal, or 4.24, while the max distance of an edge is just 3. I've tried a number of long winded approaches to get where I am and it's still not working. It goes without saying, though I'll still say it, I'm not a math wizard.

Can anyone wrap their brain around this better than me?

```
    Vector3 pos = holeCenter - terrain.transform.position;

    //flatten area
    int posX = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.x * (td.heightmapResolution / td.size.x));
    int posZ = Mathf.FloorToInt(pos.z * (td.heightmapResolution / td.size.z));
    float[,] heightMap = td.GetHeights(0, 0, td.heightmapResolution, td.heightmapResolution);
    float height =  heightMap[posZ, posX];
    int modZone = 9;
    int flatZone = 6;
    for (int x = posX - modZone; x <= posX + modZone; x++) {
        for (int z = posZ - modZone; z <= posZ + modZone; z++) {
            //if within 6 of cave ent (flat zone)
            if (x >= posX - flatZone && x <= posX + flatZone && z >= posZ - flatZone && z <= posZ + flatZone) {
                heightMap[z, x] = height + Random.Range(-0.00015f, 0.00015f);
            }
            //otherwise apply gently to the three rings around the flat area
            else {
                //if on a corner
                bool corner = false;
                if (x < posX - flatZone) {
                    if (z > posZ + flatZone) {
                        corner = true;
                    }
                    else if (z < posZ - flatZone) {
                        corner = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (x > posX + flatZone) {
                    if (z > posZ + flatZone) {
                        corner = true;
                    }
                    else if (z < posZ - flatZone) {
                        corner = true;
                    }
                }

                if (corner) {
                    //apply the new height to the old height decreasingly based on distance
                    float dist = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(posX - x) - flatZone, 2f) +
                        Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(posZ - z) - flatZone, 2f));
                    float maxDist = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(modZone - flatZone, 2f) * 2);
                    float multiplier = dist / maxDist;
                    heightMap[z, x] = (heightMap[z, x] * multiplier) + (height * (1 - multiplier)) + Random.Range(-0.00015f, 0.00015f);
                }
                else { //for an edge, only one value is in the modZone, find which, then apply
                    if (x < posX - flatZone || x > posX + flatZone) {
                        float multiplier = (Mathf.Abs(x - posX) - flatZone) / 4f;
                        heightMap[x, z] = (heightMap[z, x] * multiplier) + (height * (1 - multiplier)) + Random.Range(-0.00015f, 0.00015f);
                    }
                    else {
                        float multiplier = (Mathf.Abs(z - posZ) - flatZone) / 4f;
                        heightMap[x, z] = (heightMap[z, x] * multiplier) + (height * (1 - multiplier)) + Random.Range(-0.00015f, 0.00015f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    td.SetHeights(0, 0, heightMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after coming back to it.

```
    int modZone = 11;
    int flatZone = 7;
    for (int x = posX - modZone; x <= posX + modZone; x++) {
        for (int z = posZ - modZone; z <= posZ + modZone; z++) {
            float dist = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(x - posX), 2f) + Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs(z - posZ), 2f));
            if (dist <= flatZone) { heightMap[z, x] = height + Random.Range(-0.00015f, 0.00015f); }
            else {
                float multiplier = Mathf.Clamp01((modZone - dist) / (modZone - flatZone));
                heightMap[z, x] = (heightMap[z, x] * (1 - multiplier)) + ((height + Random.Range(0, 0.0003f)) * multiplier);
            }
        }
    }
```

I gave up the square method but it works so well the circle method works fine. Will work better for more varried situations too possibly.